# Is there any way to transfer data between Android devices without the user having to accept a connection?

Tags: android

I am currently researching task offloading strategies for mobile devices and need to be able to transfer data between devices automatically without the users being on the same WiFi network. As far as I know the user needs to explicitly accept connections both with WiFi Direct(P2P) and Bluetooth.

Is there any way around the explicit connection acceptance? Does other/better options exist?

Anything goes as long as it enables me to share data between devices in an ubiquitous fashion. Preferably without rooting the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is the Google Nearby API. It allows you to discover, connect and send data to nearby devices ***without*** any promt and without having to root the device.

Some documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/discover-devices

A good code example can be found here: https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/blob/a7df97eee9b2a553760d338babc6f24e4dc73cf7/NearbyConnectionsRockPaperScissors/app/src/main/java/com/google/location/nearby/apps/rockpaperscissors/MainActivity.java